# can't open VS 2017 projects anymore after update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Updated to 15.9.3 yesterday and I could not open any of my existing VS 2017 projects.  I get the following errors:

TypeScript package did not load correctly.
Project 'ProjName' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2017 compiler could not be created. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Any ideas?

Comment: try reinstalling?

Comment: trying repair now.  was trying to avoid a reinstall.  these were native 2017 projects, not updating from earlier vs project versions.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate when the other question does not mention `HRESULT E_FAIL`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling some of the VS extensions?  It the past the "AnkhSVN" extension has caused issues like this, try disabling them all or 1 by 1.

Comment: Tried those, but no luck.  I just finished a Repair and it seems to be working with first couple projects.  Will continue testing others.